# What is the section called when part way through a song, there is a major style change?

Tags: terminology

I remember seeing this term on Genius at one point in time and can't for the life of me remember what it is. I Googled it and went to a Wikipedia page and remember it defined it as something along the lines of, "A second part to a song that has a significant style or tonal difference than the first. There is a quick change or shift in style." I'm fairly certain it started with an "S" as well.

The term describes the specific section that has a significant style change.

If you’ve heard

King’s Dead around 2:30 the entire song shifts to a totally new style and never returns to the original. That’s what I’m getting at.

Comment: Was this geared towards popular/rock music specifically?

Comment: It was related to Hip Hop. And I’m 100% certain that it started with an S. It was a term that gives a name to the section of the song with a different style. Sorry if the question didn’t describe that well enough.

Comment: Is it "sabi"? This is a Japanese term which means a climax(?) section in the middle of a song. I don't understand this well enough to write an "answer", but this might be a clue.

Comment: Nope. Sorry again. I would recognize the word if it came up. If you’ve heard [“King’s Dead”] (https://youtu.be/VwAnsAUYnw4) around 2:30 the entire song shifts to a totally new style and never returns to the original. That’s what I’m getting at.

Comment: Genius is not an authority on anything.

Comment: If the existing answers don't contain the word you're looking for, the most likely reason is that wherever you saw that word, it is not a word that is normally used to mean what you think it means. You'll have to track that down again where you originally saw it. Either way, when talking about song sections, you probably don't want to use that word anyway, since most people won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yep. It probably isn’t a well-known term (since none of you guys can find it) It’s just driving me nuts that I can’t remember it. When I get home I’ll go through the search history on my laptop and see if I can find it. Thanks for all the help. I’ll get back if I find it.

Comment: @BrianChandler Isn't sabi in Japanese basically the same as refrain in English tho?

Comment: Could it be "stick"? What language was it in?

Comment: Or maybe it is just switching samples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, sorry for all the confusion. The term that my brain was thinking of was "Interpolation." Yes, I know that's not what I'm describing, but let me explain.

On a the Genius page for [Post Malone – White Iverson Lyrics](https://genius.com/Post-malone-white-iverson-lyrics), there's a box that gives the track information.

Under that box there is a credit titled, **"Interpolates"**:

[image: Genius Track information]

This is the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_(music)) that came up after I [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=music+interpolation&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS760US760&oq=music+in&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j0j69i60l2.5757j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), "music interpolation."

You can see that it talks about "an abrupt change of musical elements, with the (almost immediate) resumption of the main theme or idea." My brain seemed to have not remembered the second half of the description and associated the first with another word, ["Satz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz) somehow.

Anyway, thank you for all your help. I know interpolation is nothing like what I described, but I found my solution. Thanks!

Comment: But, doesn't an interpolation return to the main theme? Yet OP question says: "_the entire song shifts to a totally new style and never returns to the original._" This does not seem like a satisfactory answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: "I am fairly certain it starts with an S."

Comment: @Divide1918 -- and also ["_I’m 100% certain that it started with an S_"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67961/what-is-the-section-called-when-part-way-through-a-song-there-is-a-major-style#comment106399_67961), and later ["_I specifically remembered that it started with an S._"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67961/what-is-the-section-called-when-part-way-through-a-song-there-is-a-major-style#comment106391_67962). But, finally "_I know interpolation is nothing like what I described, but I found my solution_" at the end of the self-answer.

Comment: I'm lobbying to close the whole mess down.

Comment: @exnihilo Although [I just pulled a similar stunt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577377/word-that-combines-indicator-and-metaphor), we are all aware this question (and answer) is 3 years old, right?

Comment: @AndyBonner -- I don't know about we, but I do realize that the question is old; yet it has collected three fresh answers (one now deleted) in the last day. The question seems unfocused, not just the "S" bit, but the concept OP is after was unclear (even to the OP based on the self-answer), with the result that the answers (which seem to keep coming) are a laundry list of disparate terms, notions, and conjectures relating to song form. That is why I have voted to close the question. Maybe there is some useful stuff here, but do we need to keep collecting more of it?

Comment: There is no connection between this answer, which makes a complete mess of explaining _interpolation_, and the original question about contrasting sections. You should have just closed your question.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of rap this is almost definitely a ["beat switch"](https://www.google.com/search?q=beat%20switch%20definition&safe=active&ei=_eV2YdLgEdGZ_QapkI3wBg&ved=0ahUKEwiS0_D2h-bzAhXRTN8KHSlIA24Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=beat%20switch%20definition&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BQgAEJECOgcIABCxAxBDOgQILhBDOgcIABCxAxAKOgQIABBDOgQIABAKSgQIQRgAUIxQWLpbYPtcaAFwAngAgAGyAYgBowuSAQQwLjEwmAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz). Term doesn't apply outside that genre.

Comment: This gets the gold star. It appears to be an established term, and perfectly describes what the OP is looking for, better than their self-answer or any other here.

Answer (score 3):

That’s the called the ***bridge***. Especially in hip hop. The Godfather James Brown called out loudly and often for the bridge in many of his songs.

See also: https://beat.media/genre-guide-structure-of-a-hip-hop-song

https://genius.com/discussions/20302-Hip-hop-song-structure-is-it-too-standardised

There's a list of song terms on this site you might have heard of called Genius:

> Introduction (Intro)
>
> Verse
>
> Refrain
>
> Pre-Chorus (Climb)
>
> Chorus
>
> Post-Chorus
>
> Hooks
>
> Riffs/Basslines
>
> Scratches
>
> Sampling
>
> Bridge
>
> Interlude
>
> Skit
>
> Collision
>
> Instrumental or Solo
>
> Ad lib
>
> Segue
>
> Outro

https://genius.com/Genius-song-parts-annotated

It's obviously not *scratching*, *sampling*, or *solo*.

A *skit* is a separate section that could be anywhere in the song during which some kind of action happens like in a play or radio drama.

A *segue* is always at the end of a song but is a short section that is linking material between one song and another song. Segues are not always a significant style change, some of them actually connect the two styles of the songs and have hallmarks of both styles. Segues are also not always music. They can be quotes, sound effects, or almost anything.

It could also be called a *pivot* or *key change*.

Comment: With a bridge, the song eventually returns to the chorus, or even another verse. With the term I’m describing, the track stays with the new style until it ends. The term was used in a Geniuses track info panel, not a forum discussion.

Comment: @MichaelPayne :  Genius is not an authority on anything.

Comment: @MichaelPayne Well that sounds like a *coda* or *outro*, but I can't think of a word starting with "s". Unless it's a *segno* which means "sign", which is a mark sometimes used to indicate a jump to a bridge or coda. Also, many times the word *bridge* is used even when the music doesn't return to an earlier feel or style.

Comment: For the record, "bridge" was in common use before any hip-hop artist's **parents** were out of diapers :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you include the German word "Steg," it was in use before [the word diaper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diaper) was out of diapers.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as beating a dead horse, or at least looking it in the mouth, but... wouldn't such a segment in a hip-hop context be a [break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_(music))?

Answer (score 2):

In classical music we'd speak of the second (third, fourth...) movement.

Comment: Is it common for movements to segue into each other with no break, pause, or other division?

Answer (score 0):

Trio?

From The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48 [gcide]:

> Trio \Tri"o\, n. [It., fr. L. tres, tria, three: cf. F. trio, from the Italian. See {Three}.]
>
> [...]
>
> 2. (Mus.)
>
>    [...]
>
>    (b) The secondary, or episodical, movement of a minuet or
>              scherzo, as in a sonata or symphony, or of a march, or
>              of various dance forms; -- not limited to three parts
>              or instruments.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm fairly certain it started with an "S" as well.

Now I realize that you subsequently realized that the word didn't start with *S,* but I would add this to Todd Wilcox's answer suggesting *bridge:*

According to Wikipedia's article on [Bar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_form), the beginning of the *Abgesang* was known by the *Meistersinger* as the *Steg,* which in modern German denotes a particular type of bridge.  Wikipedia further claims (without evidence) that this is the source of the modern sense of "bridge" as an element of musical form.

Bar form is an AAB form in which the last phrase of the repeated A section is frequently identical to the last phrase of the B section *([Rundkanzone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundkanzone)).*  Therefore, the first part of the B section is heard only once.

The A section was typically shorter than the B section, and the two instances of the A section were sung using different words.  The A section wasn't necessarily half the length of the B section, but one may indulge in a bit of anachronistic comparison by noting that making the A section 8 measures long and the B section 16 measures long yields something very much like the classic 20th-century [32-bar popular song form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-two-bar_form), with the "middle eight" or bridge occupying precisely the same position as the *Steg* as a point that offers contrast where repetition is expected.  Indeed, the Wikipedia article on Rundkanzone linked above notes that Rundkanzone may be described as ABABCB or AABA, with the latter being the usual schematic description of the 32-bar form.

The "Bar" in *Bar form* isn't the same "bar" in *32-bar form.*  It couldn't be, because Bar form was established several centuries before the development of modern metrical notation using bar lines.  Wikipedia says

> The word *Bar* is most likely a shortening of *Barat,* denoting a skillful thrust in fencing. The term was used to refer to a particularly artful song – the type one composes in songwriters' guilds.

Answer (score 0):

One common description is simply that the piece is in multiple **parts**.

For example, the album/long version of Eric Clapton's ‘[*Layla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layla)’ ends with a piano-based instrumental section which was called ‘Part II’ (or the ‘Piano Exit’).

Similarly, many [Jean-Michel Jarre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Michel_Jarre) albums are divided into ‘parts’ that are joined seamlessly.

And the two halves of an album-length piece that had to be split in order to fit onto a vinyl LP (such as ‘[Tubular Bells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_Bells)’) were often described as ‘part 1’ and ‘part 2’. (In some cases they were rejoined into a single seamless track when mastered onto CD, showing that the break wasn't desired.)

Answer (score 0):

In Rock Music It's called a Change-Up, it's where the riff completely changes

Answer (score -2):

Probably [rhapsody.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapsody_(music))  It's defined as an episodic sequence of elements in one connected movement.  Prominent examples titled as such are "Rhapsody in Blue" by George Gershwin and "Bohemian Rhapsody" by Queen.

Comment: Nope. I specifically remembered that it started with an S. It was defined as "A separate section of a song that is inherently different than the rest." It was credited under the "Track Info" section on Genius to some guy. And no, it's not a bridge.

Comment: Umm, yeah, it **Is** a bridge

Comment: @MichaelPayne - again: Genius is not a valid authority on anything.  If you are look for a "Genius" term, this probably isn't the right place.

Comment: @Stinkfoot I understand that, but the actual term was defined by numbers sites and sources.

Comment: @MichaelPayne - all useless and meaningless.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - a bridge is at its name suggests - a span/link between two verses that goes off on a bit of a  tangent - like when you have to go onto a special road or approach and over a bridge to cross a river. That's how the term is always used in rock/Rnb/pop songs, although sometimes they'll fade on what is called the bridge section. The question here is about a second section that  ends the song - doesn't span anything. That's not a 'bridge'.